# SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing python

Tags: python, menu

my problem is that there is something wrong with the input command. It won't allow me to fully browse through my menu because every time i exit the menu like for instance if i press enter this message shows up "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing python" and it indicates the first input command in my first menu.

I have tried to use different syntax regarding the usages of input command. I even tried to rearrange where i should put the input command. I tried using raw_input instead of input. However when I do this every time I choose some number that SHOULD work according to my menu method, it doesn't go through. My except errors shows up instead. The first menu and the first sub menu codes are down below.

```
def main():
    player_list = read_data()

    #menu method
    print("*** Welcome to tennis game ***")
    print("1. New Game\n2. Show Table\n3. Exit")
    while True:
        try:
            x = int(input("Enter a choice : "))
            if x == 1:
                new_game()
                break
            elif x == 2:
                show_table(name, chance, wins, played)
                print("Here is the current table")
                break
            elif x == 3:
                write_data(player_list)
                print("Thanks for playing!")
                exit()
            else:
                print("Number must be between 1 and 3!")
        except NameError:
            print("Input was not a number! Please try again")
        except ValueError:
            print("Input was incorrect! Pleas try again")
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "main.py", line 179, in <module>
        main()
 File "main.py", line 54, in main
      x = int(input("Enter a choice : "))
 File "<string>", line 0

        ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: Is this Python 2?

Comment: Nah it is python 3

Comment: Are you sure it's a 3 interpreter? It looks like it's evaluating your input, which wouldn't happen in 3.

Comment: Oh.. so what is the solution if it is python 2?

Comment: Change `input` to `raw_input`. `input` in 2 will attempt to run the entered data as code.

Comment: I tried this though, when i use raw_input it manipulates my choices somehow. When i proceed to press 1 or 2 in my menu it doesn’t proceed to my submenues. Instead it registers these as invalid numbers.

Comment: Did you accidentally get rid of the call to `int`?

Comment: No did the exact same thing but with raw_ added with input

Comment: update: I tried with python 3 however this shows up:  File "main.py", line 179, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 54, in main
    x = int(raw_input("Enter a choice : "))

Comment: @DarwinUthman: What does `x` end up being, then, if not 1, 2, or 3?